# How do you connect your Salesforce site to your Salesforce Commerce Cloud site?

Tags: integration, force.com-sites, commerce-cloud

We are currently working on a Salesforce site and would like the user to get redirected to the Commerce Cloud version of the landing page upon logging in.

We would like to know, if there are some needed steps in properly redirecting the user - such as tokens and authentication -, or if we could just let the user redirect to the new site through a simple redirect algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: Is this B2B or B2C (Demandware) Commerce Cloud?

Comment: @ThomasTheunen not sure how to answer that question as  i am not to deep into commerce cloud but the site has a dx.commercecloud.salaesforce and a demandware substring on the site, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you might want to look into the following:

- https://developer.commercecloud.com/s/api-details/a003k00000VWfNDAA1/detail (this has a use-case with Experience Cloud)
- https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/usage/SessionBridge.html?resultof=%22%73%65%73%73%69%6f%6e%22%20%22%62%72%69%64%67%65%22%20%22%62%72%69%64%67%22%20

At any rate, you will need someone from the Commerce Cloud side to assist you, and possibly some custom development is required. (both on the core as on the SFCC side)

Comment: thanks for the tip but we found that once we have logged in with the experince cloud site, we can redirect to the commerce cloud site while maitaining the log in but the issue now is that we want to do the redirect seamlessly where  logging through the experience cloud site would jump directly to the commerce cloud site